# Replicating the User Profiles of multi server Farm1 into multi server Farm2

Tags: user-profile-service, user-profile-property, spfarm

I am having a multi-server farm with WFE and SQL,(say Farm1) with SP 2013 installed.
I have configured user profile service application on this farm with custom UPSA properties.

Now my issue is,i am also having another server farm (say Farm2) without having these custom UPSA properties. How to migrate all the users, its properties from Farm1 to Farm2 . There are hundreds of users in Farm1, now i need to replicate the same in Farm2.

How to achieve this?

Can i use powershell to iterate through UPSA-FARM1 and insert into  UPSA-FARM2?
or
should i use  c# code -SSOM- to achieve this?

**UPDATE**
  [image: PUBLISHING-FARM-CONSUMINGFARM-TRUST]

Comment: Are both farm on the same domain? Why not use same ups across both farm?

Comment: yes, both farms are in the same domain.  i didnt get the steps to achieve the above suggestion. @Waqas

Comment: check my answer, i think that is the best solution as we are doing the same since 2010

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint, we have a features called shared services which means you configure the service in one farm and shared across multiple farm by building the trust between farm. mainly known as publishing and consuming farm relationship.

- In your farm A, you configure UPA (with all custom properties) and now publish so that other farm can consume. your farm A will become Publishing farm. It not only serve the services to itself but others farm
- Farm B, Now we configure the trust and consume the UPA from farm A. this farm will called as consuming farm. No local UPA required.

Not all service can be shared, there are only few and UPA is one of them.

Please read this complete guide from Technet: [Share service applications across farms in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Building trust is straight forward but before doing understand the concept. here are the keyp Steps.

- Build a Trust between farm:

  - On Consuming Farm( farm B in your case), export two certificate (Root certificate and STS). move the certificate to publishing farm (farm a In your case).
  - On Publishing Farm (farm A) export the root certificate. move it to consuming Farm ( Farm B).
  - Now Import the 2 Certificate on Publishing farm ( which copied from Farm B)
  - Now Import the 1 Certificate on consuming farm ( which copied from Farm A)

Now trust is build between farm.

- Now you have to publish the Service from Farm A also called Publishing farm.
- Now set the permission on Application load balancer service.
- Now consume that service in Farm B also called consuming farm.

Comment: I think its  complicate process to follow, am little bit confused about the publishing farm .cer file and consumer farm certificates and stuck in the section "copy the certificates from  to publishing and consuming farm"

Comment: it is not complicated but you have to understand it 1st.  We are doing this long time. exchange certificate is little tricky. so understand it also test it in now lower farm